# Catch block for System.ArgumentException exists, but exception is not caught anyway, why?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
       if (typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

However I received the following exception:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Requested value 'ABC' was not found*

How is that possible? Why is the `catch` block not working?

Answer (score 9):

> Why is the catch block not working?

The `catch` block is working perfectly fine, it's just that you are looking this in Visual Studio debugger. That's what a [first chance exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) means. When you debug, all exception are shown in VS, it's just that a first chance exception might disappear if you have a proper `catch` clause. And by the way you could [configure VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/18/440150.aspx) not to show them.

Oh and just a side note: in .NET 4.0 there's the [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) method so you don't even need to `try` and `catch` in this particular snippet.

Comment: Such code `T result = default(T); Enum.TryParse(text, out result);` doesn't work because the type T must be non-nullable

Answer (score 1):

A first-chance notification is just to let the debugger know that the exception was thrown - this happens before any catch frames are considered. So in short your exception is (probably) caught.